# CodeCademy Javascript erro

Tags: javascript

Estou com problemas para criar um um for dentro do if e pegar o valor de i e dentro do segundo for com var j. Preciso comparar a var myName com a text e verificar se começam com a mesma letra e depois fazer a var hits com o comando .push() com as variaveis i e j para apresentar.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Postar o código é melhor que a imagem.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, acho que ficaria assim:

```
var text = "my name is Emerson";
var myName = "Emerson";
var hits = [];
for(i=0; i< text.length; i++){
   if(text[i] === myName[0]){
      for (var j = i; j < myName.length+i; j++) {
        hits.push(myName[j-i]);
      };
   }
}
```

Abraços, bom estudo.

Comment: Oops, tente outra vez. Cuidado: seu segundo laco 'for' deve ser interrompido quando atingir o ponto atual na string + myName.length.
COLOQUEI SEU CODIGO MAS MOSTRA ESSA MENSAGEM EM CIMA.

Comment: O que exatamente ele pede na pergunta ? Na imagem ficou cortada e na sua pergunta não ficou tão claro...

Comment: Pede isso, 
Seu segundo laço "for"
Ok! Ultima etapa: adicione outro laço for, dessa vez dentro do corpo da sua declaração if (entrs os {}s do if).

Esse laço garantirá que cada caractere do seu nome seja empurrado (push) para o array final. A declaração if diz: "Se encontrarmos a primeira letra do nome, comece o segundo laço for!" Este laço diz: "Vou adicionar caracteres ao array até atingir o comprimento do nome do usuário". Então, se seu nome tiver 11 letras, seu laço deve adicionar 11 caracteres a hits se ele encontrar a primeira letra de myName em text.
Para seu segundo laço for, tenha o

Comment: o restante.
 ele encontrar a primeira letra de myName em text.



Primeiro, você deve fazer o iterador do segundo laço começar no primeiro, para que ele comece onde o primeiro parou. Se seu primeiro laço começar em

for(var i = 0; // resto da configuracao do laco
seu segundo deve ser parecido com

for(var j = i; // resto da configuracao do laco
Segundo, pense bem em como seu laço deve ser interrompido. Leia a Dica se precisar de ajuda!

Finalmente, no corpo do seu laço, faça o programa usar o método .push() de hits. Assim como as strings e arrays têm um método .length, arrays têm

Comment: arrays têm um método .push() que adicione o que estiver entre parênteses para o fim do array. Por exemplo,

newArray = [];
newArray.push('alo');
newArray[0];   // e igual a 'alo'
Instruções
OK! Vá em frente e adicione o segundo laço for dentro do corpo da sua declaração if.

?
Dica
Seu laço deve ser interrompido quando atingir o valor do primeiro iterador

Comment: Pronto, veja agora.

Comment: Agr deu certo cara, Valeu pela atenção.

Comment: Se a resposta foi útil pra você, positive-a para ajudar outros membros da comunidade, abs, bom estudos.